# Expand a div width to the width of the sibling table which has a lot of rows and causes vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a table which has a lot of columns and hence causes a vertical scroll. How do I make a div sibling of the table expand to the full width of that table.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>
  <div style='background: green'>
    foobarbaz
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
      <td style='background: red'>foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you'll see here, the div width is only equal to the width of the body. I need the div width to match the width of the overflowing table.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean to say "columns" instead of "rows" and "horizontal" instead of "vertical"?

Comment: Yes thanks, columns not rows. Updated

Comment: Horizontal is from left to right, vertical is from top to bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap both the `div` and `table` in another `div`, and give this `div` either `float: left` or `display: inline-block`:

```
<div style="float: left">
  <div style='background: green'> foobarbaz </div>
  <table>
    ..
  </table>
</div>
```

Your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/9yKPT/
Fixed with `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/9yKPT/1/
Fixed with `display: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/9yKPT/2/

Answer (score 0):

css :
add a ID to div and to table, then do :

```
var w = setInterval(function() {
   var $div = document.getElementById("divID").style.width;
   document.getElementById("tableID").style.width = $div;
},1);
```